# When is leading/opening whitespace of a line in a tex file important?

Tags: sourcecode, chktex

According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#Spaces

> ... opening space is *generally* ignored.

I came across this using `chktex` a program to warn about possible typographic or logical errors which latex itself does not warn about.

For instance, `chktex` raises a warning if in front of `\label` or `\index` a space/tab is found (**Warning 24:** `Delete this space to maintain correct pagereferences.`).

The reason for this warning  is that labels should always be on the same page to that the label relates to (see `$ texdoc chktex`, chapt. 7, p. 19,  v1.7.4).

However, I usually indent lines within my figure environments:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\end{figure}
```

Therefore, chktex complains about the indentation of `\label{}` .

In this particular case being a floating box, everything inside the floating box is, afaik, anyhow on the same page (possibly similarly to `\begin{equation}...\n\label{eq:first}\end{equation}`).

**The question:** I wonder whether an opening space in front of `\label` can lead to a wrong pagereference?
Consider indentation in figure environments or for example this situation:

```
\paragraph{Introduction}%
  text of paragraph...%
  \label{par:end_intro}%can this be on a new page
```

Consequently, is it reasonable to extend chktex to distinguish "opening spaces" from spaces after first non-space characters to remove false positives as in my case the indentation within the figure environment?
Or in other words is the warning in my case a false positive?

If someone knows a better situation where this is relevant, I'd be happy if you could insert this to the question.

**Update** chktex version 1.7.5 (2015-12-07) and higher tracks whether the previous line ended in a comment and does not raise warning 24 in the above given example.

Comment: I'm certainly open to the idea of improving ChkTeX to handle these situations (more) correctly.  I've opened bug https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?45980 to track this issue.  Unfortunately, it may be somewhat difficult to get "right".  Especially without making ChkTeX too complicated.

Comment: The answers here suggest that chktex's advice is not so helpful here.  To turn it off entirely you can add a line `PostLink = { \index }` to `~/.chktexrc`.  This leaves the analogous warning for indices intact.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The check program is clearly being over cautious (ie wrong) to say page breaks can always happen at spaces before `\label`.

However the form you give is not optimal,. but for a different reason: If you put the `\label` after the caption (whether or not you leave a blank space or newline before it) the vertical space is adversely affected.

Consider

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\belowcaptionskip{10pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{ay\label{a}}%
  \begin{center}
    x
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{ay}\label{b}
  \begin{center}
    x
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The first form has visibly less space between the caption and the centred text as the space from `center` is merged with the space already added by the caption. However in the second version the `\write` node from `\label` prevents the `center` environment from detecting the vertical space already added so it adds its full amount of space.

*(Note the first example posted here was completely wrong as explained in the other answer. The example above has been added after the original posting.)*

Comment: `\@bsphack` in vertical mode should carry over `\prevdepth`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg in the latex sources you will see some attempts at vertical space hacks but there were "issues" and they were never really enabled.

Comment: Note that you can prevent the position of the label having an effect on the output in this example by using the `caption` package. (Even when setting `\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10pt}`)

Answer (score 13):

If no special setting to spaces is active (essentially, we're not in verbatim mode), spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored. If `chktex` complains, it's for nothing, in this case.

Actually, the program is generally wrong in warning about spaces before `\label` or `\index`, because their definition starts with `\@bsphack`, whose duty is to check whether horizontal glue precedes it and, in this case, remember it and suppress it; the next `\@esphack` command will insert the remembered the space (after the label or index entry) and ignore subsequent spaces.

Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here is an example of a ``misplaced label'' \label{mispl} according
to \texttt{chktex}.

Here is an example of a ``misplaced label'' according
to \texttt{chktex}.

\end{document}
```

with the output by `chktex`

```
ChkTeX v1.7.4 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
Warning 24 in splab.tex line 5: Delete this space to maintain correct pagereferences.
Here is an example of a ``misplaced label'' \label{mispl} according  
                                           ^
No errors printed; One warning printed; No user suppressed warnings; No line suppressed warnings.
See the manual for how to suppress some or all of these warnings/errors.
```

However, it is apparent that the typesetting is correct:

[image]

Note that your example can be simplified: there's no need for `%`.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{file}
  \caption{Caption text}
  \label{whatever}
\end{figure}
```

This is because `\caption` starts and ends with a `\par`, so `\label` is processed in vertical mode. The end-of-line after the `\includegraphics` will be suppressed by `\par` and `\label` is processed in vertical mode, where spaces do nothing.

My personal preference goes to

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics{file}

\caption{Caption text}
\label{whatever}

\end{figure}
```

I generally prefer blank lines to indentation, that makes clearer the distinction between various parts of the input. However it's just my style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The answer by David Carlisle points out that labels should be inserted into the caption command argument. Regarding the coding style: Well, I guess I do not prefer blank lines instead of indentation. I use blank lines to separate paragraphs, sections, chapters. This is the standard way for paragraphs anyway. In this context the empty line between`\ includegraphics` and `\caption` is in my opinion sensible but I would not add the other ones. I certainly appreciate that experienced users share their coding style. IMHO coding style can help to write better sourcecode.

Comment: @egreg There is [a late answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369071/28751) referring to your answer.