# Question marks in a reference to a table?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, back-referencing

I have this code and when I compile (even several times) some question marks appear on the pdf in the place where the reference should be.

```
Actually if we perform an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test on the in-sample we refuse the null hypothesis of explosive process with a p-value of 0.8226. 
This applies to all the models here presented, AR(1), AR(3) and 
ARMA(1,1). Model coefficients can be inspected in Table 
\ref{tab:daily_model_coefficients}
\medskip

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Model coefficients of the Daily Component Models\label{tab:daily_model_coefficients}}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline \hline
    $Model$ & \phi_{0} & \phi_{1} & \phi_{2} & \phi_{3} & \theta_{1}\\   
    \hline
    AR(1)   & 6.5397    & 0.8988 &- &- & - \\
    AR(3) & 6.2932  & 0.7257    & -0.0099   & 0.2162 &- \\
    ARMA(1,1) & 6.0340  & 0.9741    & -&    -   & -0.4991 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

So the point is that when I compile several times I get the following:

Actually if we
perform  an  Augmented  Dickey-Fuller  test  on  the  in-sample  we  refuse  the
null hypothesis of explosive process with a p-value of 0.8226.  This applies
to  all  the  models  here  presented,  AR(1),  AR(3)  and  ARMA(1,1).   Model
coefficients can be inspected in Table
??

I am using Sharelatex now. I will appreciate any suggestion

Comment: I have already tried writing the \caption before \label and it doesn't work...

Comment: If you get a tex error you should just look at the log, tex never tries to make sensible typeset output after an error, it just recovers enough to syntax-check the rest of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your references to work properly (on ShareLaTeX), you need to make the document compile without error. You'll note that in your example you started with a `figure` but ended with a `table`:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  % ...
\end{table}
```

Also, `tabular` header row contains math content without you inserting math mode properly.

This is what you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Actually if we perform an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test on the in-sample we
refuse the null hypothesis of explosive process with a p-value of 0.8226. 
This applies to all the models here presented, AR(1), AR(3) and 
ARMA(1,1). Model coefficients can be inspected in Table 
\ref{tab:daily_model_coefficients}.

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Model coefficients of the Daily Component Models\label{tab:daily_model_coefficients}}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline \hline
    Model & $\phi_0$ & $\phi_1$ & $\phi_2$ & $\phi_3$ & $\theta_1$ \\   
    \hline
    AR(1)   & 6.5397    & 0.8988 &- &- & - \\
    AR(3) & 6.2932  & 0.7257    & -0.0099   & 0.2162 &- \\
    ARMA(1,1) & 6.0340  & 0.9741    & -&    -   & -0.4991 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Consider using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for your `tabular` representations.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!! this worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

A nuance, perhaps, but I am under the impression that the recommended practice is to place the label after the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Actually if we perform an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test on the in-sample we refuse the null hypothesis of explosive process with a p-value of 0.8226. 
This applies to all the models here presented, AR(1), AR(3) and 
ARMA(1,1). Model coefficients can be inspected in Table 
\ref{tab:daily_model_coefficients}
\medskip
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
        \hline \hline
        $Model$ & $\phi_{0}$ & $\phi_{1}$ & $\phi_{2}$ & $\phi_{3}$ & $\theta_{1}$ \\   
        \hline
        AR(1)   & 6.5397    & 0.8988 &- &- & - \\
        AR(3) & 6.2932  & 0.7257    & -0.0099   & 0.2162 &- \\
        ARMA(1,1) & 6.0340  & 0.9741    & -&    -   & -0.4991 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Model coefficients of the Daily Component Models}
    \label{tab:daily_model_coefficients}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this using ShareLaTeX:

[image: tableExample]

Comment: no actually it is better to put the label in the caption.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle interesting, i hadn't heard that. if that is the case then i stand corrected.

Comment: I was just finding this answer... http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264115/1090

Comment: I had the problem and writing \label after \caption fixed the issue. Weird...