# Table environment prevents compiling from finishing

Tags: tables, compiling

In my report, I would like to add a table and be able to refer to it in my text.

I did the following:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c | c | c }
        \hline
        Training Data Duration [s] & Maximum SIR [dB] & Maximum SDR [dB] \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|}
        15 & 14.4353 & \textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{8.7172}\\ \hline
        25 & 14.4015 & 8.7312 \\ \hline 
        35 & \textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{14.2806} & 8.8179 \\ \hline
        45 & 14.4674 & 9.3875 \\ \hline
        55 & 14.3881 & 9.2663 \\ \hline
        65 & 14.3003 & 9.3346 \\ \hline
        75 & \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.58,0}{14.6173} & \textcolor[rgb]{0,0.58,0}{9.4663} \\ \hline
        85 & 14.5579 & 9.1584 \\ \hline
        \hline
    \label{tab:maxsirsdr}
    \caption{Maximum SIR/SDR values for different training data durations.}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I use TeXnicCenter and the `LaTeX -> PS -> PDF` mode with TeXLive. Without the `table` environment, I get the PDF in a couple of seconds. Now it does not compile at all.

What can I do? If you need more info, please ask me! And I'm sorry for abusing LaTeX terminology, my LaTeX knowledge is very basic.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! What is written in the `.log` file? Incidentally note the `\label` command should be _after_ `\caption`

Comment: Philipp's suggestion did the trick, the problem was that I've put my label and my caption into the `tabular` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the label and caption after the tabular environment.

```
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maximum SIR/SDR values for different training data durations.\label{tab:maxsirsdr}}
```

To be sure also put the label inside the caption so the counter which the label refers to is really the one of the caption and not something else.

Edit: [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) has a good point in the comments about the location of captions. It is actually preferred to have the caption above the table and not below. For an explanation you can see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table).

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you, despair has already started to kick in! And thanks for the label hint!

Comment: You can put the label also immediately _after_ the caption.

Comment: @CarLaTeX You are right. It is just one of my preferences to put it inside the caption.

Comment: The typographic norm for tables is to have the caption *before* the table (because  tables can stretch over several pages). But in any case, the label must follow the caption.

Comment: @CarLaTeX in is better than after

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264115/1090