# Figures doesn't show up in sharelatex

Tags: graphics, sharelatex, includegraphics

I am using sharelatex.com to draft a manuscript for jjap/ apex. Using the jjap.cls file for template. I've use

```
\usepackage{graphics}
```

Figures syntax:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=5cm]{peak.jpg}
    \caption{\label{figure_2}vvv}
\end{figure}
```

However, the figures does not show up after compiled and error in output.pdf.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what is error?

Comment: Images do not show up in the final pdf file though the correct syntax are used. I am also wondering what is the error.

Comment: The question was 'which error message do you see in ShareLaTeX', rather than 'what is the issue causing this'. Somewhat unrelated: the `\label` should be placed outside of the caption (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32326/). More on-topic: did you upload the image file? Is the original filename also in lower case?

Comment: And welcome to the site, of course :)

Comment: Possible solution: replace `\usepackage{graphics}` by `\usepackage{graphicx}` (with an `x`), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23075/packages-graphics-vs-graphicx.

Comment: @Marijn actually inside caption is best

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In the linked question Martin Scharrer seems to disagree with you - why would inside a caption be better than below it (and not just a difference in convention)?

Comment: @Marijn  Because placing it after can adversely affect the spacing. I have an example in an answer here somewhere I'll see if I can find....

Comment: @Marijn https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264115/1090

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem though sharelatex setting was at "normal".
`\includegraphics[draft=false,width=8cm,height=5cm]{fig.jpg}`

Comment: and how suppose should we know, that you use `draft` option in your document?

Comment: I didn't set any draft too.